# Ruby : the while loop does not work

Tags: ruby, while-loop

I have a problem with my `while` loop. The loop displays directly from last `puts` without asking for the number that is to guess (adeviner).

```
adeviner = 4
a = 0

while adeviner != 4
  puts "Entrez votre chiffre"
  a = gets.chomp.to_i
end

puts "vous avez devine le chiffre"
```

Here is what the console returns:

```
ruby test.rb
vous avez devine le chiffre
```

I would like the console to ask me to type a number and tell me if that number is good or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are accidentally using the wrong variable in your loop

```
adeviner = 4
a = 0

while a!= adeviner
    puts "Entrez votre chiffre"
    a = gets.chomp.to_i
end

puts "vous avez devine le chiffre"
```

The code above uses the a variable in the loop. a is initally set to a default of 0 (which is not the number we are trying to guess) and the loop continues until the user correctly inputs "adeviner" value.

Comment: And maybe this is could have been the condition `while a != adeviner`

Comment: I just noticed it and edited. Makes no sense to hardcode a value when it seems adeviner is used for the value the user is supposed to guess.

Comment: I agree. We have been simultaneous.

Answer (score 0):

Your while block is executed while the condition is true but your condition is never true (4 != 4 is false)